# Issue with debugger - black screen and freeeze after loading game executable

Tags: ollydbg, debugging, game-hacking

I have issue with debugging. When I try to load game executable to debugger and go to certain place in code, game window shows up but it is black and it looks freezed. I can't even go back to debugger to check what is wrong, I have to force closing of the debugger.

This happened while using Ollydbg and x32dbg.
I'm using Windows 7 64bit. Game is CT Special Forces: Fire for effect.

Answer (score 1):

I have found temporary solution to my issue. I have enabled option "Stay on top" (CTRL+F5) in x32dbg. This way I can go back to debugger to resume execution.

It would be better to also enable window mode in game, but it is not possible in this situation.

Comment: Get a second screen, it will probably help with the window focusing error. You could also hook directx to try to avoid switching to full screen mode. DxWnd is a tool that does that.

Answer (score 0):

probably anti-debugger, try enabling trace+logging to text file, then start tracing to see the last assembly instructions recorded. Also, if the window of the game appears before the crash, try putting a breakpoint right after ShowWindow/CreateWindow/CreateWindowEx/other window functions, then step to see where it freezes, or start tracing after the breakpoint that shows the window.